# Audio Recording not being saved with Video recording using UIImagePicker

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am developing an application in which I am using the image picker controller to record video, there is a video recording limitations set to maximum 2 seconds.
Here is my code while clicking on capture video to show camera UI

```
-(IBAction)capture_btn_pressed:(id)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
    {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"camera is not supported for your device" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

    if (!cameraUI)
    {
        NSLog(@"camera ui");
        cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        // Displays a control that allows the user to choose movie capture
        cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];              
        cameraUI.delegate = self;
        cameraUI.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
        cameraUI.videoMaximumDuration = 2;
        cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:cameraUI animated: YES];

}
```

**PROBLEM I am facing:**
  the maximum limit to video recording is set to 2 seconds.
so, when i tries to click on capturevideo it will be stop autometically after 2 seconds. thats fine but it is not recording the background audio with video sometimes. 
    sometime it saves audio but for 1 sec then in rest one second it is not saving audio playing with the video at the time.
  how can i sort out this problem any help